# Cordova 8: Could not install from "ios" as it does not contain a package.json file

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

I removed my ios platform and tried to add it back again, but now it says there is a problem and it needs package.json.

How do I fix ios platform so it has a package.json?

Running 8.1.2 (also tried in 8.0) with cordova-ios@4.5.4

```
$ cordova platform add ios
{ Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "ios" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mikenelson/.npm/_logs/2018-10-11T09_47_23_544Z-debug.log
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
stderr: 'npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL\nnpm ERR! Could not install from "ios" as it does not contain a package.json file.\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /Users/mikenelson/.npm/_logs/2018-10-11T09_47_23_544Z-debug.log\n',
code: 1 }
```

**Update**

8 months later I just did the same thing again, but this time I created a folder called 'android' in my project root, just to put some stuff in. So I got:

```
Could not install from "android" as it does not contain a package.json file
```

The problem, as Luigi Lopez points out in the comments, is you cannot create a folder called 'ios' or 'android' in the project root. It thinks you are wanting to install the platform from your local folder.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I'm not sure it is the same case but I was receiving the same error in a Ionic 4 project and what worked for me was to remove `ios/` directory under the project root and re-running the command:
`ionic cordova platform add ios`

Comment: well spotted, seems to be a bug that you can't have root ios/ folder.

Comment: does this interfere with ionic 4 + capacitor way of adding ios with `npx cap add ios` ?

Comment: I do not know really. The root `ios` folder, in my case, was created by capacitor, but since I did not need to use it I opted for removing it.

Comment: The cause of the problem here is not a bug that you just remove and re-add the platform. The caveat here is that you can not have any folders in your root directory called "ios" or "android".

Comment: I had this issue when switching from a Ionic 4 + Capacitor project to Ionic 4 + Cordova one - needed to remove the top `/ios` folder _before_ running `cordova prepare ios`

Comment: same is the case with 'android' just delete the android folder in the root level of your ionic app - and re-run the command

Answer (score 7):

i was also facing the same issue, seems like if we have already built a capacitor for the particular platform it will throw this error. for me when i removed android capacitor build from the root of the project and when i retried. it started working for me.

Comment: Hi @KBC, since all the splash screen images and other android details are in this folder. Is it ideal to remove it just like that?

Answer (score 2):

i have same issue after update ionic
remove path of

> /platforms/android

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 1):

So this frustrated me for about an hour and finally figured out to go into the project directory and delete the folder called "android" and then re ran the command. It forces the installation of android again with all the proper files.

Answer (score 0):

If at some point I add capacitor with cordova the capacitor-generated [android|ios] directory interferes with cordova, I recommend backing up the android directory and removing it. this will solve the problem.

```
zip –r [android|ios].zip [android|ios]
rm -R [android|ios]
ionic cordova platform remove [android|ios]
ionic cordova platform add [android|ios] --save
unzip [android|ios].zip
rm [android|ios].zip #or add in the .gitignore [android|ios].zip
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, the reason it was i trying to add an electron platform to cordova, however there was a folder called electron out of platforms folder, exact on the root, for other purposes, I believe there is some conflict, for that I renamed this folder with the name electron2 and cordova add the platform normally.